# eavesdrop on (focussed) audio stream android

Tags: android, audio

Despite reading everything I can on developer.android.com and stackoverflow I cannot figure out how to do this, though I really think it should be possible.

I'm trying to make a generic "visualizer"-style app using OpenGL ES 2.0.  I would like to be able to eavesdrop on whatever audio stream currently has focus so that I can respond to the music.  The device should be able to play music from any app they want, but then open my app and have it respond.

So far I've found plenty of ways to play, record, stream, etc. audio from a known source.  However, I cannot figure out how to eavesdrop on the device.  On the mac this is as simple as inserting an audio unit at the hardware side.  Is there anything similar in android?  Or does sandboxing prevent this entirely?

Comment: Android provides a `Visualizer` class that can grab (a low-quality version of the) audio from a specific audio session; and if you specify 0 as the session ID it will use the OUTPUT_MIX session (the global audio output). Note however that doing this isn't guaranteed to work with all combinations of Android versions and media apps.

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I did see that, and I've played around with it some.  I was just hoping for a little more detailed info from the audio stream than what Visualizer provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way of looking that this issue. Suppose the OS let you do this. Suppose there was an API that let you do

`Audio.doEavesDrop(EavesDrop callback)`

Now, imagine what some of the negative consequences could be:

- hanging the audio stream. That callback has return control at sometime, what if it doesn't for some reason? What happens to the audio stream?
- maliciously eaves dropping: your employer or a blackmailer, or  someone else who wants to invade your privacy uses this to capture every sound your phone outputs

If you were designing the platform how would you defend against this issues (and these are only the ones I could think of in a few minutes).

Do you think this should be possible? Maybe it isn't and there is(are) good reason(s) for it.

Comment: I'm not a system architecture guy, just a simple hobbyist app coder.  My question is not about whether or not it should be possible, only whether it is.  I can't tell from your answer if you're trying to be flippant or helpful.  I infer that your answer to the question I asked would be, "No, this isn't possible."  Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not trying to flippant. I also assumed you are a hobby coder as well, so I wanted to try to give some perspective on working on platforms such as this. It is important to realize there are a lot of concerns in any OS and our apps are not the only ones. That being said I doubt this is possible and it is probably for a good reason. Although android is open source and i'm sure you could find a ROM that allows this.

Comment: In that case, thanks!  I'll stop wasting my time trying to do this and figure out a different way (probably by implementing my own media player).